# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties [ Entity Framework Core ] [ OnModelCreating ]

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I use EF Core, inside my `dbcontext` class I have overridden the `onModelCreating` method to configure one property in a class to be auto-increment in SQL Server.

This is my `DbContext` class:

```
public class AppDbContext:IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public AppDbContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Service>()
               .Property(service => service.ID)
               .UseIdentityColumn(1, 1);
    } 

    public virtual DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

If you notice that my `DbContext` class is inheriting from `IdentityDbContext` because I use identity.

The problem: I get this error:

> CS0121
> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.OraclePropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.PropertyBuilder, int, int)' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.PropertyBuilder, int, int)'

[Error Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMHWR.png)

[Error Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlueX.png)

**Additional info**

I reference another project in my solution this project will play the repository role, and he prepared to work with SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL.

The project I depend on is my own project, and it is open source [that is the repository link](https://dev.azure.com/MBARK-Solutions/_git/MBRepoCore)

Please any help to fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure why is this question downvoted. Apparently it is not flaw in OP code, but the EF Core design. They use common namespace and extension methods are added anytime you add reference to a concrete database provider. Initially the guide was ever provider to prefix its own specific extension method with its name, like `ForSqlServerXyz`, `ForMySqlXyz`, `ForOracleXyz`  etc. which was fine. Then they decided to remove the prefixes and use common names, and here is the result. People should really go to their GitHub and report/complain about such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you cannot just remove the one of two problematic using.
Since those methods are extension methods (so static method) you could use them as static method :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.OraclePropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(builder.Entity<Service>().Property(service => service.ID), 1, 1);
```

Or using static import :

```
using static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.OraclePropertyBuilderExtensions;
```

Then

```
UseIdentityColumn(builder.Entity<Service>().Property(service => service.ID), 1, 1)
```

I know is not as beautiful as the fluent way of writing it but I don't think there is an alternative if you need all your using.

(I assumed you wanted to keep the Oracle one)

Comment: At now, I work with SQL Server, but your answer is helping and  working with both SQL Server or Oracle, Massive thanks bro

Comment: You're welcome :-) But do you need the using for SQL Server and Oracle in the same file?

Comment: In the future may I will need it, but I already created my own cross RDBMS generic repository project

Comment: @DEV Don't use them both in the same file. If you have to reference them both in your code not knowing which is being used at any given time, use an interface and two separate files. Trying to use both at once in the same file just makes problems like this more common and worse (though this one is all on EF honestly)

Comment: I guess it is too much to ask for the FX designers to take into consideration using a storage technology that is not Microsoft SQL Server within dotnet. Ah Microsoft...